# g_bus_get_sync returns NULL but dbus_g_bus_get_private works

Tags: c, glib, dbus

I'm working on legacy embedded code that uses the deprecated library dbus-glib.

In the legacy code, this code fragment works well:

```
GError* error = NULL;
DBusGConnection *systemBus = dbus_g_bus_get_private(DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, NULL, &error);
```

Now, I tried to get the system bus with the GDBus equivalent:

```
GError* error = NULL;
GDBusConnection *systemBus = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, &error);
```

This one fails, and `error->message` returns `Could not connect: No such file or directory`.

What's the difference?

By the way, the same call works on session bus:

```
GError* error = NULL;
DBusConnection *sessionBus = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION, NULL, &error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you run it with root privileges? In my experience with dbus access to system bus is restricted. Session bus is owned by user, so there never should be problems with access.

According to this [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html#g-bus-get-sync) you should use [dbus-address-get-for-bus-sync](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-D-Bus-Addresses.html#g-dbus-address-get-for-bus-sync) and [g-dbus-connection-new-for-address](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html#g-dbus-connection-new-for-address) when you want to establish private connection.